# Problems map and unnest data in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, tibble

I am experiencing an strange behavior ( if i restart Rstudio this code works ok, however if i run after another script running this error appears).

1. Read an xml file with xml2
2. root_players is a tibble 14 rows x 13 cols

[image]

3. node_players is a list of tibbles

[image]

4. Error when map and unlist (If i restart R this code works...but after running other code fails)
   [image]

**session info**
[image]

View code

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)


xml_filename <-"file.xml"
  
  
# Leer XML
datos <- read_xml(xml_filename)

meta_datos <- datos %>%
  xml_attrs() %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as_tibble()


root_players <- xml_find_all(datos, '/SoccerFeed/Player') %>%
  xml_attrs() %>%
  map(~as_tibble(t(.))) %>% 
  bind_rows()


node_players <- xml_find_all(datos, '/SoccerFeed/Player') %>% 
  map(~.x %>% 
        xml_children() %>% 
        map(function(.y) {.y %>% 
            xml_attrs() %>% 
            t() %>% 
            as_tibble() %>% 
            mutate(n_passes = xml_text(.y))}) %>% 
        bind_rows())

#############################
# HERE ERROR APPEARS
############################


root_players <- root_players %>% 
  mutate(n = map(node_players, count) %>% unlist()) %>% 
  uncount(weights = n)


#########################
### ERROR TRACE
#########################


Error: Assigned data `eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame())` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 14 rows.
x Assigned data has 363 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.


<error/tibble_error_assign_incompatible_size>
Assigned data `eval(cols[[col]], .data, parent.frame())` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 14 rows.
x Assigned data has 363 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Backtrace:
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context
```

Comment: Try `purrr::flatten_dfr` or `dplyr::bind_rows`

Comment: where exactly? @ciakovx

Comment: Can you post some sample data?